# How to navigate b/w cells in Google Colab when using vim editor setting?

Tags: vim, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In google colab **"default"** editor key binding I can move up/down the cell by hit `esc` and then use `j` or  `k`. But if i use **"vim"** as key binding when I enter `esc` it only exits to **normal mode** and `j` and `k` only allow me to navigate text in the current cell.

How can I move focus up or down to other cells under "vim" key bindings?

**To reproduce:** in Google Colab window enter `Ctrl + M + H` go to preferences and select **"Editor key bindings"** to **"Vim"**. Then go back try to use `j` and `k` to move up or down. the cursor will be restricted only in the current cell.

Answer (score 7):

To focus next/previous cell with vim keybindings, do the following:

`esc` Leave edit mode

`Ctrl + m, n` Select next cell

`Ctrl + m, p` Select previous cell

Note: you need to release the `Ctrl` key when pressing `n` or `p` in the above sequences.

You can remember them by: `(n)ext` and `(p)revious`

Answer (score 2):

**My solution:** in "keyboard preferences" I set `^ + j` to "Next cell" and `^ + k` to "Previous cell". You can also just use the default key bindings but I personally found it easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your own keyboard shortcuts in Colab.

Go to `Tools` ⮕ `Keyboard Shortcuts` and change `Next cell` and `Previous cell` to whatever you want.

I like `Alt/Option + j` and `Alt/Option + k`, respectively, since it is analogous to Vim's `j` and `k` meaning "go down one line" and "go up one line" respectively.

`Ctrl + j` and `Ctrl + k` do not seem to work as expected if you set them as the `Next cell` and `Previous cell` keys because Vim captures those commands to delete text, at least in my Colab.